# How do you handle a QSpinBox that can be edited by both the user and the program?

Tags: user-interface, qt

my Form has a spinBox who's value can sometimes be refreshed by the program in the background but can also be edit by user.  How should I handle this?

Comment: Programatically you can use setValue(), and handle tha value change (user edit or programatically) with the signal valueChanged(). But I don't really get what you expect, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can blockSignals() if you need to temporarily